# Unable to run spark, phoenix/hbase with Spring Boot: Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND bound slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path

Tags: java, spring, apache-spark, spring-boot, apache-phoenix

When I try to compile/build a Spring Boot project with Spark/Phoenix dependencies, it says there's too many SLF4J's, and when i try to exclude a package, it throws the above error.

How can i get them to work together?

```
    buildscript {
        ext {
            springBootVersion = '1.5.6.RELEASE'
        }
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    //THIS DOESN'T WORK
    configurations {
        compile.exclude group:'ch.qos.logback'
    }

    dependencies {
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
        /* EXCLUDING HERE ALSO DIDN'T WORK */
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
        compile('org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.10:1.5.2')
        compile('org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:1.5.2')
        compile('org.apache.phoenix:phoenix-spark:4.7.0-HBase-1.1')
        testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    }
```